# Javascript - Azure function blob storage binding vs sdk

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am creating multiple azure function (HTTP trigger) to get content from blob storage,get few metadata values of a single blob and get all metadata attributes of a particular blob type.

I am confused with using binding vs using rest API of blob storage vs azure-storage sdk.

Which is the best approach to use when creating an azure function? If you can point me to some sample documentation of this kind, that would be helpful as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple advice would be to use the binding if it works at all for your scenario, which is when you can directly bind parameters of the request to the blob name to load.

Using the binding basically saves you from the burden of coding against SDKs directly, since you just get the blob as input parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Mikhail. i tired using bindings but kind of struck with the validation the API parameters with Javascript. Check our this question of mine. [link[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700893/javascript-azure-function-blob-binding-handling-exceptions) . Do we have any performance difference with binding vs SDK ?